# Add repeating (tiled?) pattern along or on the surface of an object

Tags: mesh, texturing, sculpting

I'm in the process of creating some costumes in blender for various projects (games, art etc), and have run into this problem a few times and don't know how to solve it.

Want to create a repeating pattern like the one you see along the rim of the cloak below, that I can then extrude to make it a part of the texture.

[image: Picture example of what i want to achieve]

My idea was initially to paint/make a tile pattern with the mask tool in sculpt mode, that I can then extrude. but I can't figure out how to then seamlessly paste it along the vector I want. Let us say in this instance I want it to run along the edge like on the picture.

Comment: Instead of extruding, why don't you simply paint a black and white pattern that you'll blur a bit and use as a Bump map?

Comment: Hey, i still want it to be pretty exact in the repetition, as if it's embroidered into the fabric. By extruding i meant the expand cloth feature that you can do when painting a mask and inverting it. But the thing is if it can be done somehow by tiling it. 
I see it often in games so obviously it's possible somehow, but whether it's all being done when texture painting afterwards is the question